# Generate *.d.ts from *.scss file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, sass

I am trying to have webpack generate *.d.ts files for all my *.scss files, but for some reason webpack does not do it. I created a module rule testing for `scss` and then passing the job to `style-loader`, `typings-for-css-modules-loader`, `postcss-loader`, and `sass-loader`. My aim is to be able to use the *.scss tags within TypeScript, as in the below example in `App.tsx`. When running `webpack-dev-server` though, the *.d.ts files are not created and an error `TS2307: Cannot find module './App.scss'` is displayed instead.

*What must I do to create the *.d.ts files?*

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp-administration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Administration application for MyApp.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "My Name",
  "license": "ISC",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot --host 0.0.0.0 --config=./webpack.dev.config.js --mode development",
    "build": "electron-packager . myapp-administration --platform linux --arch x64 --out dist/",
    "deb64": "electron-installer-debian --src dist/myapp-administration-linux-x64/ --dest dist/installers/ --arch amd64",
    "compile": "yarn build && yarn deb64"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.4.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "babili-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "electron": "^4.0.1",
    "electron-installer-debian": "^1.1.0",
    "electron-installer-zip": "^0.1.2",
    "electron-packager": "^13.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
}
```

webpack.dev.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { spawn } = require('child_process')

// Any directories you will be adding code/files into, need to be added to this array so webpack will pick them up.
const defaultInclude = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.tsx',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }, { loader: 'postcss-loader' }],
                include: defaultInclude
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /\.global.scss$/,
                use : [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "typings-for-css-modules-loader", options: { modules: true, namedExport: true, camelCase: true, localIdentName: "[local]" }},
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: function () { return [ require("autoprefixer") ]; }}},
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: /\.global.scss$/,
                use : [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    { loader: "css-loader" },
                    { loader: "postcss-loader", options: { plugins: function () { return [ require("autoprefixer") ]; }}},
                    { loader: "sass-loader" }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'babel-loader' }],
                include: defaultInclude
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=img/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }],
                include: defaultInclude
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: [{ loader: 'file-loader?name=font/[name]__[hash:base64:5].[ext]' }],
                include: defaultInclude
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    target: 'electron-renderer',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'cheap-source-map',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        stats: {
            colors: true,
            chunks: false,
            children: false
        },
        before() {
            spawn(
                'electron',
                ['.'],
                { shell: true, env: process.env, stdio: 'inherit' }
            )
            .on('close', code => process.exit(0))
            .on('error', spawnError => console.error(spawnError))
        }
    }
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Style from "./App.scss";

export class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return <div>
            This text is from App.tsx
            <div className={Style.app}>
                This is my colored box!
            </div>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

App.scss:

```
.app {
    background-color: blue;
    color:gray;
}
```

Error:

```
ERROR in ./src/Components/App.scss (./node_modules/typings-for-css-modules-loader/lib??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--6-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/Components/App.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/typings-for-css-modules-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'css-loader/locals'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/myuser/Documents/myapp/administration/node_modules/typings-for-css-modules-loader/lib/index.js:9:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
 @ ./src/Components/App.scss 2:14-212 21:1-42:3 22:19-217
 @ ./src/Components/App.tsx
 @ ./src/index.tsx
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8080 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/index.tsx

ERROR in /home/myuser/Documents/myapp/administration/src/Components/App.tsx
./src/Components/App.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in /home/myuser/Documents/myapp/administration/src/Components/App.tsx(2,19)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './App.scss'.
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Comment: The initial error message shows that the typings loader is in fact loaded, but it trips over some `css-loader` internals. What really confuses me, is that you include the latter in the scss chain. Here are the (s)css rules from my boilerplate webpack config: https://gist.github.com/ChristianIvicevic/a22fa1099a0741ceb1c903263661f05b For the time being I am not exactly sure what's wrong there, maybe the gist will help you resolve it via trial and error.

Comment: Slightly offtopic: generating .d.ts files for all the scss files can pollute your source tree in the first place. You might be interested in using the `typescript-plugin-css-modules` plugin for the TypeScript server

Comment: Oh and another difference that I noticed is that you haven't included .scss in the `resolve.extensions` node of the config.

Comment: take a look at this issue on typingd-for-css-modules repo: https://github.com/Jimdo/typings-for-css-modules-loader/issues/89
Downgrading css-loader to version 1.0.1 seems to work.